# How to create a condition when timed session is set

Tags: python, session, flask, backend

So I have this page that asks for a name using HTML forms and then redirects you to another page that has on the screen hello + <the name you typed in the form>, this name is stored in a timed session that only lasts for 5 seconds after that the name is not anymore in the session and the value in the session is set to None, so when you refresh the page after 5 seconds the page says hello None, I wrote a script that is intended to redirect you to the root page where you can submit a name again after the session is set (after 5 seconds) However it isn't working, I would appreciate someone to help me solve this problem.
I use flask framework with python.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length
from datetime import timedelta

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'jajaja'
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=5)

class FormThingy(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name',validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('submit')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index(): 
    session['name'] = None
    global form
    global namePrinted
    namePrinted = 'stranger'
    session.permanent = True
    form = FormThingy()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        if session['name'] == None:
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return redirect(url_for('welcome'))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html',namePrinted=namePrinted,form=form)
      

@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('index.html',form=form,namePrinted=session.get('name'))
```

Comment: What exactly isn’t working for you?

Comment: the page should redirect to the '/' route when you refresh the page after the session is timed out (after 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC You should have added the redirect condition to your welcome page:

```py
@app.route(‘welcome’)
def welcome():
  name = session.get(‘name’)
  if not name:
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
  return render_template('welcome.html',namePrinted=name)
```